# instance Functor with data

Tags: haskell, functor

i am new to Haskell but i implemented this:

```
data Triple = T Double Double Double

instance Functor Triple where
    fmap f (T a b c) = T (f a) (f b) (f c)
```

then i tried to make the `Triple` a `Functor` but
i get this message:

```
**error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Triple’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘Functor’, namely ‘Triple’
      In the instance declaration for ‘Functor Triple**’
```

so my question is , do i really have to change the data Constructor to

```
data Triple a = a a a
```

???

this is my solution but is there a better one ?

Comment: A functor's `fmap` by definition has to work on all function types, so you can't only consider `f :: Double -> Double`. If you can only work on doubles, then you might use the not commonly used [`MonoFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor) class. If you are a beginner, you probably don't really need that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you need a `* -> *` Type for a Functor.

It has to be like this as the type of `fmap` is `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` - so as you can see `f` is *applied* to the type-parameter `a` in there.

So yep this would work:

```hs
data Triple a = T a a a

instance Functor Triple where 
    fmap f (T a b c) = T (f a) (f b) (f c)
```

`* -> *` means you need a type-constructor that is waiting for a Type and returns a Type.

For example:

- `Double` has kind `*`
- `Triple`(here) has kind `* -> *`
- `Triple Double` has kind `*` again

it's like a curried function on the type-level ;)

---

you could write something like this for your `Triple` though:

```hs
data Triple = T Double Double Double

tripleMap :: (Double -> Double) -> Triple -> Triple
tripleMap (T a b c) = T (f a) (f b) (f c)
```

and maybe this is fine enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

> this is my solution but is there a better one ?

Well, depends on what you mean by “better”. `Triple a` makes a lot of sense, if it's not really specific for `Double`.

If you have good reasons to hard-code `Double`, then you can always just make a dedicated function for mapping over this data type, like [`tripleMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67737915/745903) in Carsten's solution. [There *is*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor) also a widely used typeclass for this sort of operation though:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.MonoTraversable

type instance Element Triple = Double

instance MonoFunctor Triple where
  omap f (T a b c) = T (f a) (f b) (f c)
```

Consider also whether it even makes sense to map *arbitrary functions* over your type. Maybe what you actually want is this?

```
import Data.AdditiveGroup
import Data.VectorSpace

data ℝ³ = ℝ³ Double Double Double

instance AdditiveGroup ℝ³ where
  zeroV = ℝ³ 0 0 0
  ℝ³ x y z ^+^ ℝ³ ξ υ ζ = ℝ³ (x+ξ) (y+υ) (z+ζ)
  negateV (ℝ³ x y z) = ℝ³ (-x) (-y) (-z)

instance VectorSpace ℝ³ where
  type Scalar ℝ³ = Double
  μ *^ ℝ³ x y z = ℝ³ (μ*x) (μ*y) (μ*z)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, you need to define

```
data Triple a = T a a a

instance Functor Triple where
    fmap f (T x y z) = T (f x) (f y) (f z)
```

I use `x, y, z` to stress that these are not types, but values.

`Triple a` is the type. Its values carry inside them three values of the same type, `a`, whichever that is in each specific case, like `Double` or whatever.

Since `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, in the case of `Triple` it is `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Triple a -> Triple b`, and values of `Triple b` type carry inside them three values of the same type, `b`.

Thus we had to transform *each of the three* inside `Triple Double`, etc.